# How can I sort array after reading decimal numbers and integers from fin in C#

Tags: c#, file, sorting

I have a problem about sorting array after reading all decimal numbers and integers from txt file. The file contains both decimal and integer values. 
These values can be splited non-fixed space.

Here is my file like this

```
-12,56     76
11
-6,5 43
15
...
```

The result is shown like

```
-12,56 -6,5 11 15 76 ...
```

How can I do the process.

Comment: How do you get that result from that file? What are the parsing rules here? Why is 43 not in the output?

Comment: If you can share code snippets, we'd appreciate. :)

Comment: @Jamiec I haven't any idea about parsing rule because parsing rule cannot be fixed. There are 3 white space, 1 space space

Comment: @KevinTomas

When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe).

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *Linq*, `SelectMany` since single line can contain *several* numbers:

```
var numbers = File
  .ReadLines(@"c:\myfile.txt")
  .SelectMany(line => line.Split(
     new char[] {' ', '\t'}, 
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) 
  .Select(item => decimal.Parse(item)) //TODO: Ensure the correct Culture
  .OrderBy(item => item)
  .ToArray(); // Let's have numbers as an array

string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers);
```

Please, note `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` when `Split`ting - we remove unwanted *empty* chunks when processing lines like `"-12,56     76"`

**Edit:** If you want to try to detect where do we have and integer and where is decimal:

```
 var numbers = File
  .ReadLines(@"c:\myfile.txt")
  .SelectMany(line => line.Split(
     new char[] {' ', '\t'}, 
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) 
  .Select(item => {
     // if we succeed in parsing as int, it's int otherwise - decimal 
     bool isInt = int.TryParse(item, out var intValue);

     return new {
       isInteger = isInt,
       integerValue = intValue,
       decimalValue = decimal.Parse(item) //TODO: ensure right culture  
     };
   }) //TODO: Ensure the correct Culture
  .OrderBy(item => item.decimalValue)
  .ToArray(); // Let's have numbers as an array
```

Now if you want integer values:

```
  int[] ints = numbers
    .Where(item => item.isInteger) 
    .Select(item => item.integerValue)
 //.OrderBy(item => item) // uncomment, if you want to sort ints
    .ToArray();
```

For decimals:

```
  decimal[] decimals = numbers
    .Where(item => !item.isInteger) 
    .Select(item => item.decimalValue)
 //.OrderBy(item => item) // uncomment, if you want to sort decimals
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Can I get integer values from file as well as getting decimal values

Comment: @Kevin Tomas: here I treat all items as being `decimal`; with a help of `decimal.GetBits()` we can, technically, detect if `decimal` represent an integer value small enough to be converted into `int`

Comment: @Kevin Tomas: or you can try parse as integer, see my edit

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko How can I do sort process after getting both integer and decimal numbers' array?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is mostly the same as Dmitry's, but since it's written and it's slightly different, I figured I share.

Since the file contains both decimal and integer values, and an array can only contain one type, it makes sense to obtain an array of decimal values (since all integers can be converted to a decimal).

To split the file on *all* whitespace characters, we can pass an empty `char[]` to the `Split` method, which allows us to use `File.ReadAllText`, since it will split on the newline character(s) as well:

```
var result = File.ReadAllText(@"f:\public\temp\temp.txt")
    .Split(new char[] {}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(decimal.Parse)
    .OrderBy(i => i)
    .ToList();
```

It sounds like you want to be able to tell which items are integer values from this array, which we can do using the modulus operator (which returns the remainder of dividing one number by another). If a decimal number divided by 1 has no remainder, then it's an integer, so:

```
var integerValues = result.Where(item => item % 1 == 0).ToList();
var decimalValues = result.Where(item => item % 1 != 0).ToList();
```

Comment: How can I do sort process after getting both integer and decimal numbers' array?

Comment: They're already sorted...the original query has an `OrderBy` clause. Or are you asking something else? If so, please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I think array related with integerValues and decimalValues are seperated as two array not one array. I want to make only one array both integer and decimal numbers by sorting. How can I combine them

Comment: `result` contains both. Of course you cannot have more than one type in a single array, so I used `decimal` to represent both types. The other option would be to cast them all to `object` or `string`, but then you lose the ability to do numeric operations with them.

Comment: If result variable contains both decimal and integer numbers, there is no problem for me. Thank you @Rufus L